# Keeping iPhone 4 Free from Oil Without Using Damped Cloth

Tags: iphone

The guidelines I read on the Internet ask me to clean the oil off my iphone 4 surface by [using a slightly damped cloth](http://www.maciverse.com/clean-your-iphone-4.html).

But is there any method that I can use to clean off the oil without using damped cloth?

Answer (score 2):

Apple says:

> #### Cleaning iPhone
>
> Clean iPhone immediately if it comes in contact with any contaminants that may cause stains, such as ink, dyes, makeup, dirt, food, oils, or lotions. To clean iPhone, disconnect all cables and turn off iPhone (press and hold the On/Off Sleep/Wake button, then slide the onscreen slider). Then use a soft, slightly damp, lint-free cloth. Avoid getting moisture in openings. Don’t use window cleaners, household cleaners, compressed air, aerosol sprays, solvents, alcohol, ammonia, or abrasives to clean iPhone. ***The front and back covers of iPhone 4 are made of glass and have an oleophobic coating. To clean these surfaces, simply wipe with a soft, lint-free cloth.*** The ability of this coating to repel oil will diminish over time with normal usage, and rubbing the screen with an abrasive material will further diminish its effect and may scratch the glass.
>   — [*iPhone
>   User Guide*](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/iPhone_iOS4_User_Guide.pdf), page 54

(emphasis added)

Or in other words: remember that little piece of cloth that came with your iPhone? That's all you should need.

Comment: Pretty sure Apple stopped including those cloths when they switched to the oleophobic coating. My 3GS didn't come with one, though I don't offhand know if the 4s include them or not.

Answer (score 1):

I often **slide the phone across my sweater** (chest or sleeves) - anything that's soft, reasonably dry and clean, and won't scratch the glass will do.

Answer (score 1):

I swipe my iPhone 3GS across soft parts of my clothing, which works OK. But any microfiber cloth should work much better than plain cotton, and should also work reasonably well without being damp. You can get them at an optometrist, **glasses cleaning cloths** are usually microfiber.